# Problem with Apply Filters on URL in meta box filed of custom port type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, embed

I am using Easy Content Types for a custom post type and metabox with several fields including one called ecpt_website.

I have a custom page template which is outputting all of the fields nicely except for the ecpt_website field. the code generally looks like this for each field:

```
if(!empty ($ecpt_company)) {                     
        echo '<div class="co">';
            $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $ecpt_company );
            $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content ); 
        echo '<span class="cbt-label">Company: </span>'. $content.'</div>'; 
}
```

That will display something like Company: Example Company

The code for ecpt_website is similar and should output Html that looks like this:

```
<div class="website"><a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank"><span class="cbt-label">Website: </span>www.example.com</a></div>
```

The problem is that while every other field is working. The website url field  is outputting a lot of extra code that looks something like this:

```
<div class="web"><a href="<blockquote class="wp-embedded-content" data-secret="qaxc7Sae67"><a href="https://www.example.com/">Home</a>
</blockquote>
<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://www.example.com/embed/#?secret=qaxc7Sae67" data-secret="qaxc7Sae67" width="500" height="282" title="&#8220;Home&#8221; &#8212; Example Company Info Center" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
" target="_blank"><span class="cbt-label">Website: </span>
<blockquote class="wp-embedded-content" data-secret="qaxc7Sae67"><a href="https://www.example.com/">Home</a></blockquote>
<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://www.example.com/embed/#?secret=qaxc7Sae67" data-secret="qaxc7Sae67" width="500" height="282" title="&#8220;Home&#8221; &#8212; Example Company Info Center" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</a></div>
```

I fixed it by using this code - ie. I removed the apply_filters:

```
if(!empty ($ecpt_website)) {        

        echo '<div class="website">';
        echo '<a href="'.$ecpt_website . '" target="_blank">';               
        echo '<span class="cbt-label">Website: </span>'. $ecpt_website;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
         }
```

Do you have any idea why this happens? I looked up apply_filters and couldn't find anything similar to what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply_filters` is a function used all throughout WP in many different contexts, your issue here is the specific filter you are applying, which is `the_content`.

`the_content` filter by default runs on the main post content field, and does all sorts of transformations via a number of hooked functions: `wptexturize`, `convert_smilies`, `wpautop`, `do_shortcode`, `shortcode_unautop`, `prepend_attachment`, `wp_make_content_images_responsive`.

In your case, the markup is an embed automatically generated by WordPress when an embeddable URL is encountered within the content.

It doesn't make sense to use `the_content` filter in the case of your URL field, you should just use [`esc_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) instead:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $ecpt_website ) . '" target="_blank">';
```